# Order filter and search issue in admin order grid magento 2?

Tags: orders, collection, order-grid, magento2.4.3.p1

I have two types of order numbers( order Increment Id ) in my order table. Based on a condition i am updating the order increment id like below.

**EX - 000000767 To HTO-000000767**

I have other orders like 000000766, 000000765 etc.

When i am searching or filter the order by using `000000766` its working fine. If i use `HTO-000000767` its not working and refreshing the page with entire grid.

How can i rebuild this searching to apply based on both scenario?

And i want to order the grid with the latest order first. All my orders with the prefix of **HTO** will show first and orders with number increment id coming after.

Comment: it seems like some customization might be affecting. Because, grid not breaking If I search with increment id with text.

Comment: @RohanHapani grid is not breaking for me, everything fine except the search only. Additionally only adding the HTO prefix on sales order save after event

Comment: Disable relevent module about sales grid and check it.

Comment: if i take this order id - (HTO-000000767), search and filtering will work for 000000767, but not for HTO-000000767